# How do I change the row width in juypter notebook?

Tags: python

The output of Jupyter notebook was not able to show the value. May I know how I can change the width to fix the display problem?

[image]

Comment: I think this might have to changed in Pandas (that's what you're using, right?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one thing you must try is, reduce the number of digits after the period(.)

in pandas, there is an option
initial output:

```
    random
0   2.339650e-03
1   6.714034e-02
2   1.381005e-15
3   4.846619e-05
4   6.375477e-06
```

Changed the pattern by using the following code:

```
dd = df.apply(lambda x: '%.10f' % x, axis=1)
```

corrected output:

```
0    0.0023396498
1    0.0671403367
2    0.0000000000
3    0.0000484662
4    0.0000063755
```

instead of `.10f` you and use any less number. because there is no need to put that much digit after the period